# How to get users login history in SharePoint OnPrem?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way to get users ***Login History*** in SharePoint on-prem 2016? Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Have you tried given solution? Kindly let me know if any query or need some more help.

Comment: Did you tried it? did that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOB solution to get users Login History in SharePoint 2016. However, you can develop a custom auditing solution. You'll need to add custom code to pages which involve login action(recording the login's in your page's code. U)

You can use cookie to be a flag for checking whether there is an user just log in. After the page loaded, if the cookie is null, it suggests that there is an user just log in our site, then we can get this user’s information using JavaScript Object Model and add the information into a custom list. With this list, we can monitor user’s login details. See the reply provided by Dennis from below article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cd4d531-cb61-4d90-aa70-413267f4a735/how-to-know-login-and-logout-details-of-a-user-in-sharepoint-online-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

In addition, below post has a similar issue with you, which may be helpful to you:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/38c631e5-8158-482c-8332-5b6193098471/check-which-users-login-a-sharepoint-site-during-the-past-30-days-and-whats-the-last-login-time?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 0):

User below Powershell to get users from SharePoint.

This script will help save us developers a lot of time in getting all the users from an individual or group. So, here is the script.

1. Copy the code below to a .ps1 file.
2. Run the .ps1 file on the SharePoint PowerShell modules.
3. You don't need to do any update on the script.

> Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction
>   SilentlyContinue
>       $Currentime = get-date -format "yyyyMMdd_hhmmtt"   $filename = "FarmUsers"   $datafile = ("{0}{1}.csv" -f $filename, $Currentime)
>       $headerfile = "type,user,group,weburl,webtitle"   $headerfile | out-file -FilePath $datafile
>       $iissitedata = get-spwebapplication    foreach($farmsite in $iissitedata)   {
>       foreach ($SiteCollection in $farmsite.sites)
>       {
>           write-host $SiteCollection -foregroundcolor Blue
>           foreach ($web in $SiteCollection.Allwebs)
>           {
>                write-host "    " $web.url $web.name "users:" -foregroundcolor yellow
>                foreach ($usersite in $web.users)
>                {
>                       write-host "        " $usersite -foregroundcolor white
>                       $data = ("RootUser,{0},-,{1},{2}" -f $usersite, $web.url,$web.name)
>                       $data | out-file -FilePath $datafile  -append
>                   }
>                foreach ($group in $web.Groups)
>               {
>                    Write-host "        " $web.url $group.name: -foregroundcolor green
>                    foreach ($user in $group.users)
>                    {
>                             Write-host "            " $user -foregroundcolor white
>                             $data = ("GroupUser,{0},{1},{2},{3}" -f $user, $group, $web.url, $web.name)
>                             $data | out-file -FilePath $datafile  -append
>                    }
>               }
>               $web.Dispose()
>           }
>       }   }

[Get All Users In A SharePoint 2010/13/16 Farm Using PowerShell Script](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-all-users-in-a-sharepoint-20101316-farm-using-powershell-script)

Then try following code with loop by passing each user in below code to get last logon from AD.

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
$time = 0
foreach($dc in $dcs)
{ 
  $hostname = $dc.HostName
  $user = Get-ADUser $User.UserLogin.ToString().split('\\')[1] | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
  if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
  {
    $time = $user.LastLogon
  }
}
$dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
$UserData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "last logged on at" -value $dt
```

Here `$User` is the SharePoint User which we found from SharePoint with domain name in it.

Comment: Thanks for reverting, You have mentioned "get users from SharePoint", means each user who has permission to access SharePoint or each user from AD? Also, how can I get users from SharePoint?

Comment: I have edited my answer & added PowerShell code to get users from SharePoint farm. Please check

Comment: For your question about users, Yes all users who have access to SharePoint Farm. Not AD Users because we are looking for SharePoint user's last logon

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it worked for you?